# Qt include .lib; undefined reference to __imp__

Tags: qt, .lib

I am working with Qt creator, Qt 5.15.0, and MinGW81 64bit.

This is my first application to include an external library (libe9u_LSMD_x64.bit) to communicate with a device.
I was able to get the example source code running in Visual Studio, but I am stuck within Qt. I also tried the Qt VS Tools within Virtual Studio.

Under VS I get (with Qt VS Tools)

*LNK2019 reference to unresolved external symbol*

And in Qt creator

*undefined reference to `_imp_` ...*

Within the .pro file, I included the lib as

`win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -llibe9u_LSMD_x64`

`else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -llibe9u_LSMD_x64`

`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.`

`DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.`

I also tried renaming to .a as suggested in some other forum. It seems that the library is found and also the 64bit version is correct.

I am happy to provide more information, but since I am new with external libraries, I am not sure what is relevant to solve this.

Thanks in advance!
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the include files were written in C. Adding

```
extern "C"
{
#include ...
}
```

solved the problem.
What a unspecific error message...

D